# Why does the section "Blog Posts" show only one post when I created two posts?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a blog using HTML and CSS but I am having a problem with the blog posts. Per the picture, only one blog post (post2.jpeg) is showing up. My first post (post1.png) is not shown. I tried looking out to see if I might have made a mistake somewhere but I couldn't any errors. What may be the issue here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```css
.banner .contentBx
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: var(--white);
    padding: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.banner .contentBx h2
{
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--black);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.banner .contentBx h4
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--black);
}
.about .contentBx
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 40px;
}
.about .contentBx .content
{
    position: relative;
} 
.about .contentBx .content .imgBx
{
    min-height: 400px;
}
.post
{
    position: relative;
}
.post .contentBx
{
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.post .contentBx .postColumn
{
    position: relative;
} .about .contentBx
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 40px;
}
.about .contentBx .content
{
    position: relative;
} 
.about .contentBx .content .imgBx
{
    min-height: 400px;
}
.post
{
    position: relative;
}
.post .contentBx
{
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.post .contentBx .postColumn
{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!--Latest Blog Post-->
 <section class="post" id="post">
    <div class="title">
        <h2>Latest Post</h2>
        <p> blah hab hkj jk k k k k kk k k</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contentBx">
        <div class="postColumn">
            <div class="postBox">
              <div class="imgBx">
                  <img src="post1.png" class="cover"> 
              </div> 
              <div class="textBx">
                  <h3>lorem ipsum mn v kf vkj fvjk kf vkfj vkjf vkj fjkv fkj vkfj j jfjkjksjkjkjk  vsnlnlkn</h3>
                  <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>             
                 </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="postBox">
                <div class="imgBx">
                    <img src="post2.jpeg" class="cover"> 
                </div> 
                <div class="textBx">
                    <h3>lorem ipsum mn v kf vkj fvjk kf vkfj vkjf vkj fjkv fkj vkfj j jfjkjksjkjkjk  vsnlnlkn</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>             
                   </div> 
              </div>
             </div>
             </div>
 </section>
```

[image]

Comment: Your question has a lot of code in it. Please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you save your html file correctly? Both articles should be displayed given what code you just shared.

Comment: I put the code in vs code, then used localhost... and seems to work fine https://imgur.com/a/SQUDiu0 (the first image is visible, second is visible) is the problem is another can you tell me, pls so I can help you?

Comment: hey, @LaaouatniAnas, thanks for rechecking the code! For some reason, my code is only displaying one blog post, instead of the two. Is there a way I could share my whole code with you?

Comment: yes, put it in a jfiddle.com, and give me the link (not really all the code, if you think that the problem is in css, don't put JavaScript also... so it easy for me to help you)

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas thanks for taking the time to look over it! here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/tcfu3dsx/#&togetherjs=N47KcbhI1C